# Why can't my App find my plist file?

Tags: ios, plist

This is my first question I've posted here and am new at this, so be gentle. :-)

I'm using Xcode 6.1

My project shows these folders:

ToDoList
ToDoListTests
Frameworks
Products

![enter image description here][1]

I manually created a plist file using File->New->IOS/Resource->Property List and named it ToDoListData.plist

The plist is located in the ToDoList folder with my source files.

![enter image description here][2]

I'm using this code to read the file into an NSMutableArray named toDoItems but there are 2 problems.

1. the plist file isn't found -> in Xcode, where/what folder do I need to place plist so that it ends up in the documents folder in simulator so it can be found?
2. toDoItems variable is unused - not sure why because I thought that the code was suppose to read the values from the plist into the mutable array toDoItems

Hope that I have been able to clearly convey the problem. (I've been stuck for 4 hours)

Thanks for your help.

```
- (void)loadInitialData
{

//    JNMToDoItem *item1 = [[JNMToDoItem alloc] init];
//    item1.itemName = @"Buy milk";
//    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
//
//    JNMToDoItem *item2 = [[JNMToDoItem alloc] init];
//    item2.itemName = @"Buy eggs";
//    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
//    
//    JNMToDoItem *item3 = [[JNMToDoItem alloc] init];
//    item3.itemName = @"Read a book";
//    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];


    [self loadData];

}





-(void)loadData
{

    NSString *plistPath = [self getFilePath];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath];

    NSLog(@"Does the file exist?: %@", @(fileExists));


    if(fileExists)
    {

        NSLog(@"The value of the path is: %@",plistPath);

        NSMutableArray *toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"File does not exist");
    }


}



-(NSString *)getFilePath
{

    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ToDoListData.plist"];

}
```

Comment: Hints: 1) Your file is not in document directory/it's somewhere else, check the path
2) You just declared toDoItems, not used that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Drag the plist file into your project in XCode. It'll then come up with a screen asking if you want to copy the items and which targets to select. Make sure you select "copy items if needed" and also tick your project under "targets".

That way, it should be found in the code.

Comment: Xcode now finds the plist but says it can't be read because it is in wrong format .... wish I could post picture cause very simple, just an array of 4 strings. I dragged file out of Xcode to desktop, deleted file in Xcode, and then dragged it back into project ... now the file will not open ?

Comment: ToDoListData.plist” couldn’t be copied to “ToDoList” because an item with the same name already exists. The file is not visible in Xcode and don't know how to find and remove it.

Comment: Ahh man, well you haven't really explained your question too well, so I can't do much for you (hence why it has -4 rating). Sorry dude.

Comment: You did help because after following your instructions, it could find file, just couldn't read it. I then tried to delete the file from the project and it asks whether to send to trash or remove the reference. I think I said to send to trash when I should have said remove reference. Now I don't know how to remove reference to ToDoData.plist because I can't find it, so I can add it back in.